# How to add environment value in servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

We have dev, predev, uat and prod environments, I need to write code for implementing different environments, our application is developed in servlets. jsp

I need to access below code in .jsp or .servlet

## application.yaml

env:

- name: ENV_DEV
  valueFrom:
  configMapKeyRef:
  name: config
  key: dev

If possible please share me the code

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In general I don't think you should write your code that depends on environment it runs in. This is because your code becomes too coupled to the environment, if tomorrow you'll want to run the code somewhere else (another environment might eventually come up) - you'll have to change the code.

Instead of doing that, try to understand what are the implications of environment and map it to business features that code should react to.
For example, lets say, you want to run H2 database in dev env. and Postgres in prod (just an example).
So you could write the code like that:

```java
if( env == dev) {
   run something in H2
} else if (env == prod) {
   run something in Postgres
}
```

However consider a different approach:

Dev env implies that you'll work with H2 so define a configuration per environment (externally in some file or something).

```yaml
dev.yml
dbType : H2
```

```yaml
prod.yml
dbType: Postgres
```

Now your product should support H2 and Postres so the previous code snippet becomes:

```java
if( dbType == H2) {
   run something in H2
} else if (dbType == Postgres) {
   run something in Postgres
}
```

So you're not depenedent on the environment anymore.

Now as for the technical part of how to supply such a configuration - it depends on your deployment. One approach would be adding an environment variable that points to a file. Another approach would be using some configuration server (its more advanced) - this is all depends on your actual requirements, so without more details its kind of hard to provide the solution that will work for you in the best possible way...

Comment: In order to get environment variable, in which file, i need to add parameters

Comment: Yes, you can specify init parameter in web.xml see http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Servlets/Setthecontextparametersinwebxml.htm or use environment variables and read them in the servlet for example